# How to specify key of resource in razor mvc helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, helper

We apply meta:resourcekey on elements in web forms for resource files. I want to know the equivalent one for Razor MVC 4 helpers.

```
<asp:label meta:resourcekey="lblName" ID="lblName" runat="server" ...
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: A good article [here](http://dotnetbuilder.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/globalization-in-mvc-3-with-razor/)